# How to handle large Qt resource files on a system with a very slow storage?

Tags: c++, qt

An embedded system has the hardware required to run Qt Quick applications, has a nice CPU and good GPU, but has an extremely slow non-volatile memory.

As the GUI has a lot of images, I have the following dilemma:

- if I put the images into a qrc file, it will be compiled into the executable, so the application will load very slowly.
- if I load the images as normal files on-demand (not all of them are visible in every menu and dialog), the program will hang for a while whenever such a menu or dialog opens, waiting for the images to be loaded from flash memory.
- Managing the individual images manually (for example, in a manually written background thread) seems like too much effort, so I hope there is a more elegant solution.

Is there a nice way to use the Qt resource management system to load the resources in the background? The images used in the main GUI should be loaded while a splash screen displays a nice progress bar, and the rest can be loaded silently in the background after the main application starts. A nice addition would be if I could selectively load and free up certain resource files (in some states of the application some resource files are not needed, so it would be nice if I could free up some memory)

Is there an elegant way to solve this with the Qt resource system, or do I have to manage all my images manually?

Comment: Can you load them in the background on the screen before the resources are used?

Comment: I doubt you can decide what to load first and after within resources, I think it could be possible to have some kind of "hook" into resource loading but with Qt it is always a bad idea using "tricks" because you maybe loosing multi-platform capabiliies. If I was in your place I would load images as normal files in a sort of smart cache where you load first what you really need and then i background what you may need later and you try to keep as much as possible in ram.

Comment: @Marco : Even if I couldn't specify in what order the files in a qrc are loaded, it would be very useful if I could manage for a qrc file to be loaded in the background while the application is already running. If the need arises, I could then use multiple qrc files, and load only the one I need. My problem is that if a qrc is compiled into the executable, the executable will be very large, and therefore start very slowly.

Comment: I guess I'll have to resort to a halfway solution, with Dynamic Resource Loading and using `registerResource()`. I'll still have to manage them individually, but it's still much better than managing individual image files.

Comment: What are the images that you load? Are they photographic, or the type of images that you can can generate programmatically and make use of the CPU / GPU instead, creating them from draw calls? If you can't generate them, I'd opt for manually handling the loading of the next gui menu images in advance. Of-course this depends upon the design of the flow of your GUI.

Comment: Not sure if this applies to you, but `QPixMap`s are automatically cached, regardless if the image is embedded in the executable or if it comes from a file.

Comment: Note that you can compress your files if you decide to pile them up in an external binary resource. See the `-compress` option in the `rcc` [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/rcc.html).

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be helpful to mentioning some notes (in my experience):

- Resource images which will be used as interface resources (such as
  icons), should be embedded in default `qrc` resource file. They
  should have small size.
- Some resource files are large and will not
  be loaded frequently. These resources can be loaded dynamically as
  external files.
- You should load asynchronously large images (using
  `asynchronous` property).
- You should use `Loader` element for
  loading large/complex components.
- You can use UX solutions/tricks
  to making delay invisible (like showing progress bars, playing
  micro-animations, transitions,...).
- As I researched some hours, it
  seems to be helpful to use dynamic resource files (`rcc` files)
  with/without compression for large resources OR use native file
  system.

Answer (score 1):

So you don't want resources embedded into the application, because that bloats the executable and it is too slow to load, and you don't want resources outside the application, because they are too slow to load?

First of all, being a resource in the executable doesn't mean you are an object ready to use in memory. In most cases you will still have to load that data into a Qt object, for example an image file into a `QImage`. You will still get that delay. And unless that part of the data is paged in memory, it won't be any faster than reading from disk directly.

The best and pretty much only thing you can do is mask the delay out. This is only possible if you know which resources are needed for each application state, and every time you change a state you load all the data needed for states you can get into from the current state. This way resources will be loaded ahead of time, and hopefully before you get to the new state requiring then. The downside - you will have to keep tracking those objects and you will have memory overheads - as you could possibly be loading data for more than one states but enter only one. The upside - most of the loading can be hidden from the user, and you only preload a subset of the entire data, not all the data. Naturally, reducing the footprint of the resources as much as possible is a must.

Other than that, there isn't much you can do. If your storage is slow, the best solution is to upgrade it if you can, second best - be realistic about what you can expect from the hardware.

Comment: In default, qrc file is managed as compressed resource within main execution file. since loading a large compressed file is time consuming, startup will be slow.